# Unable to find MergedDictionaries in app.xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have created a WPF application (named "Ferhad.Wpf"). Then I added two class libraries with names "Ferhad.Wpf.Core" and "Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles" to the solution.

There is only "Resources.xaml" in "Ferhad.Wpf.Core".

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="#FFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundNormal" Color="#3F3F46" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrushNormal" Color="#54545C" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrushHighlighted" Color="#6A6A75" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But there are also "ButtonStyles.xaml" and "Styles.xaml" in "Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles".
Here is "ButtonStyles.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.Core;component/Resources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="StandartButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundNormal}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushNormal}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and "Styles.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandartButton}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Ferhad.Wpf.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Everything seems fine at design time of MainWindow.xaml, but when running the application an exception is thrown: `Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.`

I have googled about it, but nothing has helped. I have tried to change the BuildAction of files, but that did not help either.

**UPDATE:**

The exception is on line number '8' and line position '18'.

And the inner exception is: `{"Could not load file or assembly 'Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles, Culture=neutral"}`

Comment: Can you post the inner exception and line number as where it was pointing? Which resource dictionary was it throwing an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to add a reference from `App` to `Core`, `SystemStyles` needs the `Core` so if the build process only copies the `SystemStyles` it does not have its `Core` assembly.

```
App
-> SystemStyles
-> Core

SystemStyles
-> Core //Not strictly necessary because the build process does not copy the 
        //reference to the App project anyway and the resources
        //are not resolved at compile-time

Core
-
```

Comment: It worked. :))  I dont know how i made it? :)) Anyway, really very thanks. It takes my 2 hours.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: You could say it is a bug in the build process, in theory only the `App->SystemStyles` & `SystemStyles->Core`references should be necesseary...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyles.xaml" />
```

To

```
  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
```

Comment: This should not change anything.

Comment: Sometimes, the resources will just find references through some weirdness and throw an exception that it can't load and changing it to a pack uri source works. Like Image Source uris explicitly saying just the filename might work but sooner it will throw exception and needs the pack